# Custom application exception HTTP status code

Tags: tapestry

I've used the #3 method from [this](https://tapestry.apache.org/overriding-exception-reporting.html) page to customize the application exception page when in production mode, however my error page returns 200OK HTTP status code while I want it to return 500 Internal Server Error (as it is in development environment).

I am not sure how to change the status code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the handleRequestException implementation of the [DefaultRequestExceptionHandler](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/internal/services/DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.html) which is used by default, you can see that the response status is set to 500:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

You would have to do something very similar in your code (not tested):

```
public RequestExceptionHandler decorateRequestExceptionHandler(final Logger logger, final ResponseRenderer renderer,
    final ComponentSource componentSource, final Response response,
    @Symbol(SymbolConstants.PRODUCTION_MODE) boolean productionMode, Object service) {
    if (!productionMode) return null;

    return new RequestExceptionHandler() {
        public void handleRequestException(Throwable exception) throws IOException {
            logger.error("Unexpected runtime exception: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            ExceptionReporter index = (ExceptionReporter) componentSource.getPage("Index");

            index.reportException(exception);

            renderer.renderPageMarkupResponse("Index");
        }
    };
}
```